# URL Returns 404 from tomcat

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, http-post

i am currently very confused about one situation i have the following piece of code:

```
public String loginDetail(CloseableHttpClient httpClient, Userinfo user) throws Exception {
    HttpPost httppost = null;
    try {
        List<NameValuePair> formParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        formParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("j_username", user.getUsername()));
        formParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("j_password", user.getPassword()));

        HttpEntity loginEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(formParams, "UTF-8");
        httppost = new HttpPost("http://<URL>/j_spring_security_check");
        httppost.setEntity(loginEntity);
        CloseableHttpResponse loginResponse = httpClient.execute(httppost);
        String responseStr = new String(EntityUtils.toString(loginResponse.getEntity()).getBytes("ISO_8859_1"),
                "GBK");
        loginResponse.close();
        if (responseStr.contains("/common/index.jsp")) {
            return "Success";
        } else if (responseStr.contains("error=2")) {
            Utils.recordIncorrectUser(user);
            return Constants.INVALID_USER;
        } else if (!responseStr.contains("error=3")) {
            return Constants.InvalidPassword;
        }
        return Constants.SYS_ERROR;
    } finally {
        if (httppost != null) {
            httppost.abort();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I run the above-mentioned code in a standalone application it works fine and returns the response from the website, but when I put the same code in the tomcat web application with access the same URL it returns me 404 error. "HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found."

Can anyone please help me why this should be happening? is there anything related with redirects or something?

Edit:
i just realized it cannot access any external URL from webapplication in tomcat, but from standalone application i can access all, is there any configuration i need to make in tomcat?

Comment: check your url | check tomcat is properly up?

Comment: yes tomcat is up and running, i can debug it, all the internal webservices can be accessed as well, one thing to add is the url i am accessing is external URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it got resolved, in my case i performed the following things

1. disabled my firewall  (didnt work)
2. removed my Antivirus (avira) and restarted my computer (vola it worked)

hope it helps someone who faces such problem

**Edit:** Another problem i discovered was i was using Astrill VPN that was causing to work as local resolver that's why it was giving 404 error exiting it also helped